# Rich text box image not displaying

Tags: php, image, upload, tinymce

I am using tinymce for rich text box but I am not able to display image however into database and into database.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?
I am using this script also:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    theme: "modern",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
        "emoticons template paste textcolor moxiemanager"
    ],
    toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
    toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
    image_advtab: true,
    templates: [
        {title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1'},
        {title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2'}
    ]
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert the image into database you will need to insert the image base64 encoded into the editor.

Comment: will you plz elaborate?

Comment: encodeing an image in base64 will give you string containing ASCII characters that you can convert into an image. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Comment: i've $sql="INSERT INTO posts(subject,content,category,post_date)
 values ('$subject','$content','$category',NOW())"; in content i've use rich textbox(tinymce)

Comment: no, you would need to insert the images into the editor first as base64-encoded string - database interaction stays the same. the other option is to just use an image tag with src refering to the image location (in the rte content)